# Create a function named public()

Tags: php

How can I create a function named `public`? When I do this:

```
function public() { ... }
```

I get this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), 
expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

**EDIT** I must do this :( I want to create a controller `/account/profile/public`. For this I must create a function public in the class...

Comment: Basically, you can't. `public` is a language construct, meaning it has a special use and you can't have it as a method name.

Comment: In reply to your edit: Use routing or htaccess to serve requests for `foo/public` with `foo/my_function_name` if you must. You simply can't have a method with this name.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yeah, this will work. It should be the answer btw :) so I can select...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has reserved keywords, public is one of them. You should never use a reserved keyword as a name. Read about reserved keywords here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Edit:

For Routing this value, you can add a route with this value, but just for URL, you cant call a element inside PHP using a reserved keyword.

Exemple : /account/profile/standart

Route Name : 'standart-route' => array('url' => '/account/public/');

Then you can access using the name public, and you are not using it on names on php.

Comment: There must be some solution. See Edit in Question plz.

Comment: Or simply use .htaccess rewrite rules.

Comment: i prefer routes by let all the organization to php. but .htaccess works perfecty to this job.